# libssp.so.0 problem apt

Tags: server, apt

I'm trying to execute any kind of apt-get update (or install ..).
every operation brokes on this:

[image: error while loading shared libraries: libssp.so.0]

[image: terred while processing]

I've tried to autoremove packages, clean, -f, dist-upgrade - all unsuccessful

ubuntu server 12.04

Comment: What is in /opt/bitnami/ ? It looks like an extra software you have installed that is the problem when you start a perl that is installed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have an proper answer but if a workaround fits your need.

I have the exact problem (last line):

```
# ldd .perl.bin 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcf1ff000)
    libperl.so => not found
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007f3eae3e9000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f3eae1e4000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f3eadee8000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007f3eadcaf000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f3eadaab000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f3ead88e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f3ead4cf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f3eae60a000)
    libssp.so.0 => not found
```

So i "cd" into /opt/bitnami/perl/bin and did

`mv .perl.bin .perl.bin.bitnami && ln -s /usr/bin/perl .perl.bin`

I was then able to update my box without errors.

I first tried to amend my $PATH to remove the /opt/bitnamii paths but nothing done the trick. Looks like the perl.bin shipped with bitnami is to old :

```
# file .perl.bin.bitnami 
.perl.bin.bitnami: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.4.0, not stripped
# file /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=0xded7e7bb8672f54eacf8f90a2262dba723e11c29, stripped
```